# What is an unambiguous expression for 3 3 3 3 3?

Tags: american-english, british-english, numbers, mathematics

In some country there is a unit for countable quantity.

```
3 3 3 3 3
```

For example, they say "5 count-unit of 3".

But in English we just say "five threes". But then

```
3 3 3 3 3
```

and

```
5 3
```

are hard to distinguish.

I believe I heard someone saying '5 lots of 3', but I am not sure the expression is correct or suitable for 3 3 3 3 3.

Q1) what is unambiguous English expression for 3 3 3 3 3 ?
Q2) Is '5 lots of 3' acceptable expression for 3 3 3 3 3 ?

Comment: If you mean 'how to describe what you see written', I would say 'Five three**s**'.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it. Now, five threes (3 3 3 3 3) and five three (5 3) are different, but I am finding better expression for (3 3 3 3 3).

Comment: And in print, as you are citing, "Here are five *three*s." Shades of the _Two Ronnies_' 'Fork 'andles' sketch.

Comment: You can try five separate/individual threes.  Which also prevents 33333.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English, those numbers would sometimes be expressed as "quintuple three", although expressions like "double three" and "triple three" would be more common since quintuples don't come up very often.

This construction is much less common in American English, however, which doesn't really have an exact equivalent to it  that avoids the ambiguity you describe that could come up, for example, giving someone a phone number on a bad cell phone connection where the difference between "Five three" and "five threes" could be hard to hear.